# Best behavior in C: for loop variables locally or globally defined

Tags: c, for-loop, scope, global-variables, local-variables

Which is considered the best behavior in C and what are the pros cons of the two possible following options?

#### OPTION 1 (global variable):

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // do something
}
```

#### OPTION 2 (local variable):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // do something
}
```

**EDIT:** Assume I don't need the variable after looping over it.

Comment: How ‘global’ is the global variable?  Defined outside the loop, or defined outside any function?  Only the latter is truly a global variable.  And using a truly global variable as the loop control is almost always an appalling idea.

Comment: There are cases where this is just opinion based. But there are also cases where they behave different. If you want to use the final value of `i` after the loop (in case you might exit the loop via `break`) you must define it before the loop header.  BTW: Normally your option 1 still uses a local variable in that function. Really global variables are barely used for that purpose and should be avoided as global variables should generally avoided.

Comment: Preferably use option 2 unless you need to know the value of  `i` once the loop has finished.

Comment: Option 1 will work with all C compilers.  Option 2 requires a compiler that accepts C99.  By default, GCC 4.x or earlier will reject option 2, though it can be told to accept it (via `-std=c99` or similar).

Comment: In the end it is a matter of opinion what is better in what circumstances. I would say that a programmer needs to be able to read and write both.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is to limit the scope of variable to the minimal required one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: “Only the latter is truly a global variable”: For a definition of “truly” that means false. C does not have a global name space.

Answer (score 4):

The main benefit of option 1 is that you can use `x` outside the body of the loop; this matters if your loop exits early because of an error condition or something and you want to find which iteration it happened on.  It's also valid in all versions of C from K&R onward.

The main benefit of option 2 is that it limits the scope of `x` to the loop body - this allows you to reuse `x` in different loops for different purposes (with potentially different types) - whether this counts as good style or not I will leave for others to argue:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < 100; x++ )
  // do something

for ( size_t x = 0; x < sizeof blah; x++ )
  // do something;

for ( double x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.0625 )
  // do something
```

However, this feature was introduced with C99, so it won't work with C89 or K&R implementations.

Comment: Re "*whether this counts as good style or not I*", Seeing as limiting data access to code that needs access to it is one of the major tenets of CS...

Comment: @ikegami: I was talking more about using the same identifier (`x`) for different things in the same code.  I've done something very similar to the above, using the same identifier for different types in consecutive loops.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. This is a third option, that is sort of intermediate:

```
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        // do something
    }
    // use x
}
```

This is equivalent to the 2nd option, if there's no code between the two closing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Always try to declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

This makes your code more readable and clear.

For example consider the first code snippet with a modification

```
int x;

//... some other code

for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // do something
}
```

When the reader will read this code snippet and encounter the declaration

```
int x;
```

he well not know what this variable means and where it is used.

If you will rewrite this code snippet the following way

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // do something
}
```

then this code will confuse readers because they will think that the variable x is used somewhere else after the for loop though actually it is used only in the for loop.

So the best way is to write

```
for ( int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This comes down to opinion. Some coding styles require programmers to declare all variables at the beginning of a function.

Comment: @Cheatah I agree that there are many low-qualified programmers that invent their styles.:)

Answer (score 1):

General good practice in C is to always reduce scope of variables as much as possible. This reduces namespace clutter and naming collisions, plus it is good design to encapsulate logic as much as possible to make it self-contained and readable.

Meaning that option 2, declaring the loop iterator inside the loop, is the preferred practice.

The only time you should use option 1 is when you need to use the value after the loop has ended, or when you are stuck with an old C90 compiler.